# Forward traffic via libnetfilter_queue

Tags: c, linux, netfilter

I have a need where i need to forward traffic with libnetfilter_queue to another server, after adding some informations in it. 
 
Problem is that i'm stuck on the forward part , i can do what i want with the packet and add the needed informations, though even while requeing the packet (with NF_REPEAT) with another destination IP, my packet will still be processed by my machine and not sent to the remote host.

From what i understand, the problem lies in the iptables.
My iptables config is

```sh
iptables -A INPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0 --queue-bypass
iptables -t nat -m mark --mark 1 -A PREROUTING -s $clientIP -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination $serverIP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

The configuration forwards the traffic when i stop my program (and thus the queue is bypassed), so maybe it has something to do with where i put my hook in the iptables flow?
It would also help if i can masquerade the traffic but not mandatory (would be better for our logging tools to know where the packet comes from)

If it's usefull, here is the forward function

```c
void reroute(struct iphdr *buffer){
        //TODO
        printf("The address before rerouting is : %" PRIu32 "\n", buffer->daddr);
        fflush(stdout);
        buffer->daddr = server_ip;//__bswap_32(server_ip);
        printf("The address is : %" PRIu32 "\n", buffer->daddr);
        return;

}
```

Here is the calling function

```c
int ProcessPacket(struct iphdr* buffer)
{
        
        //Get the IP Header part of this packet
        struct iphdr *iph = buffer;
        printf("IP Protocol is: %d\n", iph->protocol);
        switch (iph->protocol) //Check the Protocol and do accordingly
        {
                case 1:  //ICMP Protocol
                        print_icmp_packet(buffer);
                        break;
                case IPPROTO_TCP:  //TCP Protocol
                        print_tcp_packet(buffer);
                        process(buffer);
                        reroute(buffer);
                        printf("The address after rerouting is: %" PRIu32 "\n", buffer->daddr);
                        return 2;

                        
                        break;
                default: 
                        return 1;
                        break;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The libnetfilter interesting part is

```c
 if(routing == 2 && !nfq_get_nfmark(nfad)){
                printf("destination address is, %x \n", ip->daddr);
                struct tcphdr *tcp_header = nfq_tcp_get_hdr(pkBuff);
                if(tcp_header != NULL )
                {
                        nfq_tcp_compute_checksum_ipv4(nfq_tcp_get_hdr(pkBuff),ip);
                }
                return nfq_set_verdict2(queue, ntohl(ph->packet_id), NF_REPEAT, 1, pktb_len(pkBuff), pktb_data(pkBuff)); //queued again so that once marked they can be forwarded
        }
        else if(routing ==1){
                return nfq_set_verdict(queue, ntohl(ph->packet_id), NF_ACCEPT,0, NULL);
        }
        else{
                return nfq_set_verdict(queue, ntohl(ph->packet_id), NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL);
        }
```